# The loop gods strike again - How to keep socket connected despite GUI mainloop?

Tags: python, sockets, client-server, tkinter

**Question**

How to run the Tkinter `mainloop` and an infinite server loop simultaneously, in the same script?

**Background**

I am in the process of creating a GUI server in Tkinter ([Python 2.7.3](http://docs.python.org/2/)). So far, the GUI works correctly, the Server works correctly, *but* I am having issues integrating the two. As far as I know (correct me if I am wrong) the server needs to be running on an infinite loop to accept new users. Sadly, the GUI also needs an infinite loop. I am wondering how to have both loops running at the same time.

My current mainloop function looks like this (`s` is the socket object):

```
def mainloop(s):
    while True:
        channel, addr = s.accept()
        print "Connected with", addr
```

That is obviously needed to keep the server running (I think.) The issue though, is that this loop comes before my `mainloop` and thus I have problems with that. If I do it the other way around, the Server is never opened.

**Full Code**

My server code is [here](http://pastebin.com/Aj541zUi), and my client is [here](http://pastebin.com/C2PjVWUU).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use the thread module to open your server mainloop in a new thread.

Replace

```
mainloop(s)
```

with

```
thread.start_new_thread(mainloop, (s,))
```

Then you can call root.mainloop() to run Tkinter, just like you did.

---

**UPDATE**

Per A. Rodas' comment below, it's preferred to use the newer `threading` module which is compatible with Python 3.

so you can replace

```
mainloop(s)
```

with

```
threading.Thread(target=mainloop, args=(s,)).start()
```

Comment: This can be a solution; however, [according to the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html), you should consider using the high-level `threading` module instead of `thread`.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use Twisted http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/

It integrates Tk loop into its reactor loop(which does the networking)http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.internet.tksupport.html ,and you can easily build protocols....

Answer (score 0):

Run them in separate threads.  See the [threading module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) for more information.