# How to use Global Variables defined in Function loops

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7

For my [simple socket server](http://pastebin.com/aCeVY90q), I need to have a function called `serverloop`(I am trying to improve my functions skills.) In this function, the loop constantly attempts to connect with potential clients:

```
def serverloop(s):
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print "Connected with", addr
```

But, `conn` is needed for other functions to run:

```
def send_msg(conn):
    #Send some data to the remote server
    my_message = raw_input(">>>")


     #set the whole string
    conn.sendall(my_message)
```

I attempted to force conn to be global with the line `global conn`, but I still received an error:

```
NameError: global name 'conn' is not defined
```

**NOTE:** I have to use threads.

**How can I call the conn variable despite it being defined within a function?**

Comment: How is `send_msg` called? Where from? How is it related to `serverloop`?

Comment: **Where** did you add the line `global conn`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I added that in a different version. To replicate the issue, put the `global conn` within the loop, above the accept line.

Comment: @DanielRoseman That function is used to send messages.

Comment: Well I guessed that. But you didn't answer my questions at all. Where from? How?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Here is the pastebin of the entire code: http://pastebin.com/aCeVY90q

Answer (score 1):

You are using threads, and `conn` is *not yet set* by the time you call `RECEIVE`.

The fix would be to either *not use threads*, or to at least set `conn` to `None` then poll if it is set to something different in `main` before attempting to pass the value to `RECEIVE`.

Comment: But, I *have to use threads.* I was [creating a GUI socket Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754878/the-loop-gods-strike-again-how-to-keep-socket-connected-despite-gui-mainloop), but I recently realized that the issue was the server, not the GUI.

Comment: @xxmbabanexx -- Also, you're calling RECEIVE with the wrong number of arguments (If I read your code correctly) ...

Comment: Can you please elaborate on setting "conn to None then poll if it is set to something different in main before attempting to pass the value to RECEIVE"? Or at least provide a link so that I can learn to understand it myself.

Comment: A simple `while conn is None: time.sleep(0.1)` loop could be enough to check if the connection actually has been made. **However**, your `serverloop` thread will immediately *replace* `conn` again as it too loops and assigns a new value to `conn` every iteration. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve here.