# Placement of conn, addr = s.accept()

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

I am currently working on a very basic client-server system in python 2.7

I want to have a **tkinter window running as well as a socket listening**. The socket part of program should print out any received data. If I place `conn, addr = s.accept()` before `root.mainloop` then the tkinter window does not show up until I close the socket. If I place it after `root.mainloop()` then the socket doesn't print the data until I close the tkinter window.

So my problem is this: **Where should I place `conn, addr = s.accept()` ?**

Comment: You should learn Twisted and let it worry about where to put the call.

Comment: Found the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754878/